# Pass parameter name with a " / " in Angular Ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

The if statement has to compare the elements in the column with "N/A"
and change  bg color if true.. but it is not returning true even if there are elements named "N/A". Please refer the below code.

```
{
    headerName: "Gen Barcode", field: "genbarcode", width: 130,
        cellClass: function(params) {
            return params.value === "N/A" ? "grey" : "null";
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your value for `params` [i.e. console.log(params)]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to test to see where your problem is.

Make sure that the value "N/A" is actually being passed.

```
{ headerName: "Gen Barcode", field: "genbarcode", width: 130,
    cellClass: function(params) {
        console.log(params.value === "N/A");
        return params.value === "N/A" ? "grey" : "null";
    }
}
```

Make sure that the CSS class "grey" is actually working.

```
{ headerName: "Gen Barcode", field: "genbarcode", width: 130,
    cellClass: "grey";
}
```